# Why file isn't being deleted with file.delete()?

Tags: android, file

I can't delete file from sdcard.

```java
File toDelete = new File(fname);
boolean result=toDelete.delete();
```

The result is false. Reads and writes of the same file is working in same app running.
No opened streams. No exceptions raised.
I have tried to make it writable just before deletion this way

```java
toDelete.setWritable(true);
```

with no effect.
How does it possible that the system can write and read, but can not delete the same file???

Comment: Pleas add some more code about how you build up the file path

Comment: I can read and write this file, there are no problems with path or permissions, the system just rejects to delete it

Comment: i think you are creating file programatically or runtime?? m i right?

Comment: The file was created by the same app at previous start

Comment: ok thats why file not deleted.... can you show us create file & delete file code.

Comment: Try this answer : [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18867424/968538), it worked for me...

Answer (score 3):

use below code it may help you.

```
            File fdelete = new File(file_dj_path);
        if (fdelete.exists()) {
            if (fdelete.delete()) {
                System.out.println("file Deleted :" + file_dj_path);
            } else {
                System.out.println("file not Deleted :" + file_dj_path);
            }
        }
```

Refresh gallery  after delete image

```
sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED,
 Uri.parse("file://" +  Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));
```

check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10716773/1168654

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your answer, but file is not deleted all the time and it stays on sd-card as I can see through ./adb shell

Comment: can you show us your more code about file path in your question..??

Answer (score 1):

Try doing this

```
 File fileToDelete = new File(YourPath);
 boolean deleted = fileToDelete.delete();
```

Remount your card again and check

```
 sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED,
                     Uri.parse("file://"
                               + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));
```

Comment: This way doesn't work