# Android deleting file from sd card

Tags: android, camera

I have a problem, I am taking picture saving it on sd card and sometimes I want to delete the image, using

```
getActivity().getContentResolver().delete(imageUri,null,null);
```

And I got error that there is something wrong with my uri.. but it works when I display that image, so where is the problem?

Comment: Do you have write permission for the SD card?

Comment: Yes I have. I am writing those photos to that sd card.

Comment: Put the error trace in your question, we can only guess at this point.

Comment: when you wanna delete the image ?

Comment: E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown URL file:///storage/***/Image_name.jpg
 thanks the error I get, I want to delete photo that has been taken like 20 photos before.

Comment: Why not use new File(path).delete()?

Comment: Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10716642/android-deleting-an-image