# Delete zip folder in android

Tags: java, android, delete-file

```
Map<String, String> zip_properties = new HashMap<>();
zip_properties.put("create", "false");
URI zip_disk = URI.create(name);

/* Create ZIP file System */
try (FileSystem zipfs = FileSystems.newFileSystem(zip_disk, zip_properties)) 
{
   Path pathInZipfile = zipfs.getPath(name);
   // System.out.println("About to delete an entry from ZIP File" + 
     pathInZipfile.toUri() );
   Files.delete(pathInZipfile);
   //System.out.println("File successfully deleted");
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I have create zip folder for multiple images in internal storage.Now i want to delete Zip files from the location and recreate same name zip folder in android.

```
Perform above code for delete zip folder but its not working
Please help me if anyone have solution
Thanks in advance..
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I delete files programmatically on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24659704/how-do-i-delete-files-programmatically-on-android)

Comment: @RanjanDas I try your code but it deletes only content of zip files but not delete zip files.

Comment: give path of zip file, not contents of it.

Comment: Zip_Folder_Path :: /storage/emulated/0/PhotoResizer/PhotoResizer_1533707372194.zip

I use above path for deleting zip folder, but only content of zip folder is deleted not zip file.

Comment: Only do arraylist.clear(); in my case when recreate zipfile.
its solve my problem.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

after using delete() method in your File. 
filePath is a String containing the path to your zip file.

```
File file = new File(filePath);
```

//must check if deleted is true. It is true if the file was successfully deleted

```
boolean deleted = file.delete();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 Use below method

     /**
     * Clear/Delete all the contents in file/Directory
     *
     * @param file file/folder
     * @return true on successfull deletion of all content
     * <b>Make sure file it is not null</b>
     */
    public boolean clearDirectory(@NonNull File file) {
        boolean success = false;
        if (file.isDirectory())
            for (File child : file.listFiles())
                clearDirectory(child);
        success = file.delete();
        return success;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try!

```
public static final String ZIP_FILES_DIR = "Download/FolderNAME";    

File directoryPath = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+ File.separator + ZIP_FILES_DIR);
    if (directoryPath.delete()) {
        //do whatever you want
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

File file = new File(deleteFilePath);
boolean deleted = = file.deleted();

deleteFilePath is a String containing the path to your zip file.

if deleted is true. It is true if the file was successfully deleted.