# Who maintains MediaStore.Audio.Media database in android?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

Suppose a mp3 file is downloaded via a browser. Will the `MediaStore.Audio` database be updated by android automatically or the music player app which is installed will need to update the db with a new entry in all related db's (like MediaStore.Audio.Albums etc..)

Answer (score 0):

`MediaStore.Audio` database update by android automatically when broadcast `android.intent.action.MEDIA_MOUNTED` fire.

[how fire broadcast](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10716773/1168654)

Comment: What is the the trigger to this Broadcast intent? Can a music player app rely on android that it will update the database and thus we will always get the correct result as soon as the new file is downloaded?