# How to delete file along with it's path on storage?

Tags: java, android, file

I am trying to delete a video file from the gallery but the below code is not working properly.
It deletes only the content, but the video remains in the gallery and when I try to play the video it says that the video cannot be played.

```
public void deleteVideo(View view)
{
    File f = new File(delete);
    f.delete();
    if(f.exists())
    {
        try
        {
            Toast.makeText(
                TestVideoRecordingActivity.this,
                "inside try",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
            ).show();
            f.getCanonicalFile().delete();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
    dialog.dismiss();
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [android : deleting an image](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10716642/android-deleting-an-image)

Answer (score 0):

Just add below line after you programatically delete the video file -

**For api < 14**

```
sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED, Uri.parse("file://" + 
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));
```

**for api >= 14**

```
MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(MainActivity.this, 
new String[] { Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() }, 
null, 
new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {

    public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {

              Log.i("ExternalStorage", "Scanned " + path + ":");
              Log.i("ExternalStorage", "-> uri=" + uri);
    }
});
```