# how to delete an image from android when its URI is known?

Tags: android, android-intent, uri, gallery, delete-file

Im developing an android app which selects an image from the gallery in one activity and displays it in another.But when I try to delete the selected image it doesnt delete.I'm passing its uri between the two activies. Many thanks in Advance!!!!

Here's my Code :

ACTIVITY HOMESCREEN

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
     super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

     if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {
          Uri uri = data.getData();
          Intent i = new Intent(this, Imageviewer.class);       
          i.putExtra("imgpath", uri.toString());
          startActivity(i);
     }
}
```

IMAGEVIEWER ACTIVITY :

```
Uri imageUri;
imageUri = Uri.parse(intent.getStringExtra("imgpath"));
File fdelete = new File(imageUri.toString());

    if (fdelete.exists()) {
         if (fdelete.delete()) {
               System.out.println("file Deleted :" );
         } else {
               System.out.println("file not Deleted :");
         }
    }
```

Comment: In the `ACTIVITY HOMESCREEN` you converted the `imgpath` to string once and then in the imgviewer activity you did the same and you get the `URI` again which is the problem..Do it like this : Get the imgPath first from URI, Convert it to string the send it to the next Activity(`IMAGEVIEWER` in your case) then there is no need to convert it or using it as `Uri`, Just retrieve the path then use it. Also, Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10716773/4409113

Answer (score 4):

First you must take real path of image:

```
//getting real path from uri
private String getFilePath(Uri uri) {
    String[] projection = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};

    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null, null);
    if (cursor != null) {
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(projection[0]);
        String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex); // returns null
        cursor.close();
        return picturePath;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Then you can delete this file like below:

```
Uri imageUri;
imageUri = Uri.parse(intent.getStringExtra("imgpath"));
File fdelete = new File(getFilePath(imageUri));

if (fdelete.exists()) {
     if (fdelete.delete()) {
           System.out.println("file Deleted :" );
     } else {
           System.out.println("file not Deleted :");
     }
}
```

Comment: getFilePath return null always

Comment: @hkchakladar maybe you don't have correct access to read storage? If your android version is higher than 5 you must ask runtime permission from user.

Answer (score 0):

Try this : (In the second `Activity`) `ImageViewerActivity` in your case.

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
        String receivedPath = intent.getExtras().getString("imgpath");
        File fdelete = new File(receivedPath);

        if (fdelete.exists()) {
            if (fdelete.delete()) {
                System.out.println("file Deleted :" );
            } else {
                System.out.println("file not Deleted :");
            }
        }
```

Also you can debug your codes line by line to see and check if the `ImgPath` is getting correctly or not!

Answer (score 0):

With kotlin you could do: `uri.toFile().delete()` and its deleted

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).