# Delete image after it was uploaded

Tags: android

Created an app that takes picture and uploads it to my pc. But I need to delete it from phone after it was uploaded.

```
File file = new File(String.valueOf(photoURI));
file.delete();
```

Tryed using that but it didn't helped me.

Full code:
https://pastebin.com/mvdjRULa

Comment: Refer this link :-https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10716642/android-deleting-an-image

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10716642/android-deleting-an-image

Comment: Tryed it and it didn't work. Maybe I didn't something wrong, will try it again

Comment: bool = file.delete();
                    if (bool)
                        Log.i("Delete", "successfullly");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see that you have member variable `Uri photoURI` only meant for deleting the file. Instead make `photoFile` member variable and call `photoFile.delete()` after you upload the file.